# display a list of html content, is it ok to use list of webview

Tags: android, html, listview, webview

I need your help now, please give me any suggestion.
In an application, we have to show a list of html content.
My solution is: using a Webview in each listview item to display html

But the problem is: webview size increase as per item (in scroll action).

Is there anything wrong. 
May Webview is not designed for loading content in each item of list, and my solution is not good.
But if I use TextView to load content, It could display only simple html content
Ex: TextView can't display html table or image tag.

If using Webview is not good and it can't be used in my case, I have to explain why. But I can't find any convincing evidence.

Can you suggest me an evidence for this problem. And more, please give me a solution.

Comment: Better avoid using webview in listview, instead on listview show main heading in textview and on click of that go to next screen and show webview.

Comment: you can parse html tags retrieve the content and then use a listview to display them. Look for html parsers